# What will happen if two plugins provide task with the same name in Grunt?

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-requirejs

For example, both `grunt-contrib-requirejs` and `grunt-requirejs` provide a task called `requirejs`. What will happen if I installed two plugins? Which plugin will be used to run the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the order in which you define your `grunt.loadNpmTasks()` calls:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-requirejs');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
```

Will overwrite the `grunt-requirejs` and load the `grunt-contrib-requirejs` version, where as:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-requirejs');
```

Will overwrite the `grunt-contrib-requirejs` and load the `grunt-requirejs` version.

To see which one gets called (in which order) when you run, you can call Grunt with the `-v` flag to make it`s output more verbose.

Also remember, never be afraid to poke it with a stick and see what happens!